# Problem with template Quote

Tags: quote, org-wide-defaults

I try acess my template quote in sandbox, but every time show me this error

- You do not have Edit access to one of the two records you are trying to merge

I am a System Administrator.

Someone had this problem? I need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are editing template in developer sandbox.Currently you can only edit quote templates in full sandbox.There is an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gA7qAAE) posted in idea exchange.

Comment: Thanks sf.dev

But how I know my sandbox type, to know if is developer or not?

Comment: @Lisyy check for storage limit under setup-->Data Management-->Storage Usage.If Data Storage limit is 200 Mb then it is developer sandbox.If data Storage limit is 1 Gb then it is developer pro.If it is 5 gb then it is partial sandbox

Comment: Sorry, I find my sandbox type, really is a developer type.

Thanks a lot for the help.